# How to redirect internal URLs to end with trailing slashes with docker inside ECS cluster(ec2)

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I have my frontend website hosted in docker containers in AWS ECS cluster(EC2).I want to redirect my internal pages to pages with trailing slashes at the end. what i want is even if the URL is typed or directed to https://us.springverify.com/api-integrations (without a trailing slash) the URL should redirect to https://us.springverify.com/api-integrations/ (with trailing slashes).

My setup - Docker Containers->EC2->ECS->Load Balancer->Route53.
My Docker File.

```
FROM node:8
WORKDIR /sv-us-frontend
COPY package.json /sv-us-frontend/package.json
RUN npm install
COPY . /sv-us-frontend
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
EXPOSE 4444
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, ALB doesn't support URL rewriting or request modification. You have the following options to achieve what you want:

1. Add a webserver e.g. nginx in front of your services/application containers. Then you can use nginx to implement the rewrite rules.
2. Add a CloudFront distribution in front of your ALB and use the CloudFront Functions to rewrite the URL [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67970915/5032092).

Best, Stefan

Comment: @HarryKris Was this answer helpful in solving your issue?

Comment: can you mention a little more on the nginx part. How can i achieve this with existing ECS containers